# AngularJS: Show appropriate form elements depending on model type

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have an Angular model which has `ConfigValues`.  Essentially its a `Dictionary` passed in from C# that looks a little like:

```
{
   Name: "Config Name",
   Value "True",
   Type: 0 // boolean
}
```

Some are boolean, some are ints etc.  What I'd like is to intelligently show a `checkbox` (or perhaps a `select`) when I encounter a bool type and then show a normal `input` when I see another type.

How can I do this?

```
<table>
    <tr ng-repeat="(key, val) in module.ConfigValues">
        <td>{{key}}</td>
        <td><input type="text" ng-model="val.Value" ng-disabled="module.saving" /></td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: maybe you could use the `ngIf` directive.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try with `ngIf`:

```
<table>
    <tr ng-repeat="(key, val) in module.ConfigValues">
        <td>{{key}}</td>
        <td>
            <input type="text" ng-model="val.Value" ng-disabled="module.saving" ng-if="val.Type !== 0" />
            <input type="checkbox" ng-model="val.Value" ng-disabled="module.saving" ng-if="val.Type === 0" />
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

If you are going to have more types, maybe you can try with `ngSwitch`:

```
<table>
    <tr ng-repeat="(key, val) in module.ConfigValues">
        <td>{{key}}</td>
        <td>
            <span ng-switch="val.Type">
                <input type="checkbox" ng-model="val.Value" ng-disabled="module.saving" ng-switch-when="0" />
                <input type="text" ng-model="val.Value" ng-disabled="module.saving" ng-switch-default="0" />
            </span>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```